# Only one of tofile and todir may be set

Tags: apache, maven, ant

When I compile a project with the POM contents as given below with `clean install post-site -Pdev`, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) on project test-copy: An Ant BuildException has occured:
Only one of tofile and todir may be set.
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<copy todir="temp/config" file="temp1/temp1.conf" tofile="temp2/temp.conf" failonerror="false">... @ 5:98 in Projects/TestCopy/test-copy/target/antrun/build-main.xml
```

How do I fix this problem?

Ant script that got generated during compiling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="maven-antrun-" default="main"  >
<target name="main">
  <echo>Base Dir:</echo>
  <copy todir="temp/config" file="temp1/temp1.conf" tofile="temp2/temp.conf" failonerror="false">
    <fileset file="/Users/Projects/TestCopy/test-copy/*.conf"/>
  </copy>
</target>
</project>
```

POM Contents:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>temp.test.copy</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-copy</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>test-copy</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                    <echo>Base Dir1: </echo>

                                <copy todir="temp/config" failonerror="false">
                                    <fileset file="${basedir}/*.conf"/>
                                </copy>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles> 
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id> 
            <build>
                <plugins> 
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution> 
                                <phase>post-site</phase> 
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal> 
                                </goals> 
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                    <echo>Base Dir: </echo>
                                        <copy file="temp1/temp1.conf"
                                              tofile="temp2/temp.conf"> 
                                        </copy>
                                    </tasks>                                    
                                </configuration> 
                            </execution>
                        </executions> 
                    </plugin> 
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>     
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the missing `id` tags in your executions. Since you did not define an id, Maven will use `default`. Now you have a default execution in your base pom as well as one in your dev profile.

Since the id is identical, maven simply merges poth definitions, resulting in the rather weird mixed ant that you got.

So simply add to *different* `<id>` tags to bot executions and you are fine.

**Additional note:**

You should *always* included ids in your executions, in addition to preventing effects like your problem, they server als as documentation, because the id is printed out during the build. So choose something meaningful like: `copy-configuration-dir` and `copy-single-config-to-site`.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and your answer solve it. Without <id> the ant plug-in is merging rules in a strange way.